# Using corrcoef and all p values returned as 1 or 0

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to test the correlation of 4 sets of data using the `corrcoef` function in matlab. Each one contains 50 values. Starting out, the data are in a .csv file wtih 4 columns of 50 values each. I've put all 4 sets into a column vector labeled y:

```
y=[[set1] [set2] [set3] [set4]]
```

So y is a matrix of 4 colums of 50 rows.

I've called the corrcoef function using

```
[r,p]=corrcoef(y)
```

When I run this code, I get a 4x4 r matrix with a diagonal of 1's and sets of identical values above or below it, which seems correct because the 1's must be the correlation of one set to itself and the identical values above and below the diagonal are just the correlations of the same two sets repeated (i.e. `set2` to `set1` vs. `set1` to `set2`).

However, the matrix of p values I return seems all wrong, and I'm not sure why. I get a 4x4 matrix with a diagonal of 1's, and all the values above and below are 0. Clearly this is incorrect because it's saying that the probability of getting the perfect correlations by chance is 100% while getting the "imperfect" correlations by chance is almost impossible.

Can anyone help show me what I'm doing wrong here? I can supply more details if needed.

Edit: just wanted to mention I'm trying to follow the instructions from the mathworks help page:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html
In their example, they do show the p-values along the diagonal as all being equal to 1, can anyone tell me why that is?

Also, the p-values aren't exactly equal to 0, they're just absurdly small, like 5.9601e-10, which is what is making me feel like something is wrong.

Edit2: I've also tried computing the correlation coefficient between two of the sets using excel's corr function, and it gives me the same value for r as matlab does.

Comment: Seems like this is just saying that you 4 data vectors are completely uncorrelated, as if they were constructed for that very purpose. Where did this data come from?

Comment: And of course the p values along the diagonal have to be 1, as you are comparing a vector with itself!